# Weka unlabeled attribute...does it has to be part of the Instance to get classified?

Tags: java, android, classification, weka, inference

Easy and fast doubt. Lets say my ARFF looks like this:

```
@attribute outlook { sunny, overcast, rainy }
@attribute temperature numeric
@attribute humidity numeric
@attribute windy { TRUE, FALSE }
@attribute play { yes, no }

@data
sunny, 85, 85, FALSE, no
sunny, 80, 90, TRUE, no
overcast, 83, 86, FALSE, yes
rainy, 70, 96, FALSE, yes
rainy, 68, 80, FALSE, yes
......
```

5 attributes (4 without the class attribute). When I create an Instance to classify it, should I introduce a value for the attribute class? Like "?" or "-1" or something like this. Does it changes anything? Example:

```
ArrayList<Double> featureVector = new ArrayList<Double>();
featureVector.add((double) 0);
featureVector.add((double) 85);
featureVector.add((double) 85);
featureVector.add((double) 1);  
//featureVector.add((double) -1); -> Class attribute

Instances instances = classification.featureVectorToInstances(featureVector);
result = classification.classifyInstanceToString(instances.firstInstance());
```

And the functions:

public Instances featureVectorToInstances(ArrayList featureVector){

```
Instances instances = new Instances("Instances", attributes, 0);    
DenseInstance instance = new DenseInstance(attributes.size());

for(int i = 0; i < featureVector.size(); i++)

    instance.setValue(i, featureVector.get(i));

instances.add(instance);    
//Set class attribute
instances.setClassIndex(attributes.size()-1);

return instances;
```

}

public String classifyInstanceToString(Instance unlabeled) throws Exception{

```
double clsLabel = cModel.classifyInstance(unlabeled);
unlabeled.setClassValue(clsLabel);
return unlabeled.classAttribute().value((int)clsLabel);
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: anyone?? it passed over a week and still no right answer...:(

Answer (score 0):

if I understood correctly:

you have to provide a label for train intances. Why: the learning algorithm builds a model using traiing data, then using the model it classifies new instances, and then it evaluates his own class predictions, comparing them to the original labels. Thus without the labels no evaluation of algorithm performance is possible.

Comment: Mmmm, I don´t know if I explained myself good. Yes, its necessary to provide labels for train instances, but what I meant is if is necessary to provide to every instance which we want to classify the class attribute value (the label, the one we want to find out!). Ive add some code to the main post...maybe now is more clear